# Grunt, замена пути до изображения в css

Tags: node.js, grunt

При компиляции проекта в Grunt необходимо пройтись в скомпилированном css файле и заменить все пути до изображений на нужные.

Нужно это для того чтоб у всех сторонних пакетов была своя папка с изображениями, например `dist/images/vendor`.

Файл в котором нужно выполнять поиск, скомпилирован из сторонних стилей, установленных через bower. Соответственно у каждого подключаемого стиля свои пути до картинок, по этому было принято решение все картинки загружать в отдельную папку а пути до них переписать на нужные.

У нас есть:

1. Скомпилированный стиль, лежит по пути `dist/css/bundle-vendor.css`.
2. Стиль fancybox, лежит по пути `vendor/fancybox/source/jquery.fancybox.css`.
3. изображения fancybox скопированы по пути `dist/images/vendor`.

В итоге из этого:

```
#fancybox-loading, .fancybox-close, .fancybox-prev span, .fancybox-next span {
    background-image: url('fancybox_sprite.png');
}
```

на выхлопе нужно получить такой вид:

```
#fancybox-loading, .fancybox-close, .fancybox-prev span, .fancybox-next span {
    background-image: url('../images/vendor/fancybox_sprite.png');
}
```

Хотелось бы еще узнать, есть ли решение, которое сохранит пути от корневой, папки в нужную. И в данном случае мы получим следующее:

```
#fancybox-loading, .fancybox-close, .fancybox-prev span, .fancybox-next span {
    background-image: url('../images/vendor/fancybox/source/fancybox_sprite.png');
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> npm install grunt-string-replace --save

Grunt.js

```
grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-string-replace');
```

Add Task

```
string-replace
```

grunt.initConfig add

```
'string-replace': {
        inline: {
            src: [
                'dist/css/<%= that.name %>-vendor.css'
            ],
            dest: "dist/css/<%= that.name %>-vendor-rep.css",
            options: {
                replacements: [{
                    pattern:  /:(\s*)(url\(\s*[\"\']*)(?:[^\"\']+\/)?([^\/\"\'\)]+[\"\']*\s*\))/ig,
                    replacement: ': $2../images/vendor/$3'
                }]
            }
        }
    }
```

Thx [@Visman](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/456529/11620)