# RegExp поиск и замена пути до изображения в css

Tags: регулярные-выражения

Нужно выполнить поиск и замену строки в css файле. Причем найти только название изображения с расширением.

Пока поиск выполняю так с исключением

```
/:(\s*)url\(((.(?!.*https:|.*http:|.*base64|.*data:image))*)\)/ig
```

И замену

```
:$1url(\'../dist/img/vendor/$2\')
```

В этом случае я заменяю путь аналогичным путем. И получаю такой результат

```
background-image: url('../dist/img/vendor/"../images/preloader.gif"');
```

А нужно из такой строки

```
background-image: url("../images/preloader.gif");
```

получить такую

```
background-image: url('../dist/img/vendor/preloader.gif');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Регулярное выражение выходит таким

```
%(url\(\s*[\"\'])[^\"\']+\/([^\/\"\']+[\"\']\s*\))%i
```

Пример применения на php

```
$css = preg_replace(
    "%(url\(\s*[\"\'])[^\"\']+\/([^\/\"\']+[\"\']\s*\))%i", // ищем совпадение
    "$1../dist/img/vendor/$2", // меняем на это
    $css
);
```

**UPD**
Дополнение по итогам обсуждения в комментариях.

Регулярное выражение для выделения подстроки:

```
/(url\(\s*[\"\'])(?:[^\"\']+\/)?([^\/\"\']+[\"\']\s*\))/ig
```

Подстрока для замены:

```
$1../dist/img/vendor/$2
```

Тестовый пример https://regex101.com/r/kU7cC9/3

Comment: не знаю правильно ли я сделал, но в моем случае строка должна иметь такой вид

    /:(\s*)url\((\s*[\"\'])[^\"\']+\/([^\/\"\']+[\"\']\s*)\)/ig

замена ':$1url(\'../dist/img/vendor/$3\')'. Но в этом случае я получаю такой результат background-image: url('../dist/img/vendor/preloader.gif"'); замену делаю через Grunt

Comment: еще в данное выражение не попадают строки такого вида url('fancybox_loading@2x.gif')

Comment: @vitaly63, вы бы указали в вопросе более широкий ряд примеров, а не с одним файлом. Для `fancybox_loading@2x.gif'` вообще не понятно, что должно происходить.

Comment: по вашему примеру `/:(\s*)url\((\s*[\"\'])[^\"\']+\/([^\/\"\']+[\"\']\s*)\)/ig` работает не плохо, но только для строки которую я давал в примере, только вот в конце из строки берется закрывающая кавычка. И получается `url('../dist/img/vendor/preloader.gif"');` по хорошему нужно отрезать весь путь, если пути нет выдать только название конечного файла

Comment: @vitaly63, кавычке лишней появляться не от куда. Регулярное выражение протестировано было в php. Какую замену подставляете для этого регулярного выражения `/:(\s*)url\((\s*[\"\'])[^\"\']+\/([^\/\"\']+[\"\']\s*)\)/ig`?

Comment: `':$1url(\'../dist/img/vendor/$3\')'`

Comment: @vitaly63, а теперь посмотрите, что я подставляю за место найденной подстроки в своем ответе и поймете, что вы лишнее вводите.

Comment: будьте добры покажите на примере https://regex101.com/r/kU7cC9/2

Comment: @vitaly63, https://regex101.com/r/kU7cC9/3

Comment: большое Вам спасибо, все работает

Comment: есть последний момент нужно доработать регулярку она не заменяет пути без кавычек т.е. не работает для таких примеров
`background-image: url(fancybox_sprite@2x.png);`
`background-image: url(../images/fancybox_sprite@2x.png);`

Comment: @vitaly63, пробуйте https://regex101.com/r/kU7cC9/4